# How to calculate fuse size for primary coil?

Tags: transformer, fuses, step-down

How do you calculate fuse size for primary coil? I have an 230V AC to 18V DC.

What are the steps please?

Comment: It is very unclear what your question applies to, what is your circuit? Even if it is a very standard circuit (transformer, bridge rectifier) please include it so we all know what we're talking about. Even a picture of such a circuit is enough, find one using Google. You mention no current so there is no way to select a fuse.

Comment: It is for this transformer. https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0f46/0900766b80f46e63.pdf

Comment: Well, you need a fuse rated for more than 230V, but that's most fuses. But the most important detail is the current, and you left that out.

Comment: Okay so anything above 230v How do I do that?

Comment: @M2T156 Look at how much current you expect to be going through the fuse and pick a fuse rated for slightly--but not too much--more. You'll need to determine if you want a standard or slow-blow fuse, too.